# How to create option group or assign an option group to an instance using the rds-aurora module [terraform]

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-aurora, terraform-modules

I have created an aurora cluster with one instance using the rds-aurora module in terraform, but I do not see a way to assign an existing option group to the instance or a way to create an option group in the clusters creation.

Tried using option_group_name as a variable but this did not work obviously as this variable is not part of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Internally this library uses aws_rds_cluster_instance & aws_rds_cluster_instance resources and not db_instance (they are different things)

To db_instance you can set option_group_name but to aws_rds_cluster_instance you can't

In RDS instances you can only control parameter groups and via this library it works via create_db_parameter_group variable (to set parameters for a single db) or via create_db_cluster_parameter_group (to set parameter for the whole cluster)